# Java - Image Opacity

Tags: java, blur

I have been making a video using pure Java. I would like to put in a pop-up menu for players when every they hit ESC. I have the menu setup but it looks really quite ugly. I would like to make the menu blur the image behind it.

For example on the new iOS 7 on Apple devises a lot of the things like the dock blur to whatever is behind it. There is an example of what I am trying to achieve below!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use something JXLayer, as it will allow you to apply filter effects to the components that it covers.

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799451/java-blocking-focus-from-jcomponent/19801009#19801009).

Comment: I am sorry but I new at this. Could you please send me some source code?